# How do I can get response data after I post it?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, axios, frontend

I want to get data (= user id) after I post
How to I store a response data to variable..?

```
   async function start() {
    const req = {
      'user-num': count,
    };
    const response = await axios.post(NumURL, { req });
    setState(response.data);
    // userid(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    // return data  
  }
```

I want to get the response data...
and the backend api just give json format like
{"user-id" : 3}

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are only sending user-id from the backend, however if you can search the user after getting the user id, fetch the data again from the server on the specific endpoint
eg:

```
setState(response.data);
const response = await axios.get(`NumURL/${id}`, { req });
setState(response.user);
```

just do the get request again on the specific endpoint, after getting the id.